# Unable to Install Tensorflow , tensorflow-base-1.12 error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, anaconda

I am trying to conda install tensorflow in an environment which I created.
The downloading and extracting of packages starts but one particular package named 'tensorflow-base-1.12' only gets 76% downloaded and "FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')" this error is shown.

Below is the screenshot
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT2Ha.png)

Comment: Can you rerun the install in verbose mode?  `conda install tensorflow -vv`

Comment: What channel are you using? Does `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow` also produce the error?

Comment: I received the same error today.  I am running windows 10 and a relatively fresh install of conda.  I also updated my base conda install.

Comment: Try creating a separate environment and then pip install it. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I found that the package directory path is too long.
Reinstall anaconda to shorter path (C:\Anaconda in my case), it will work well.

Comment: In my case, I had to create a separate environment and pip install it.